# Django returning case sensitive results despite correct database collation and use of icontains

Tags: python, mysql, django, encoding

I have the following DRF view:

```
class DictionaryFuzzyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Dictionary.objects.filter(disabled=False,).order_by(Length('simplified').asc())
    serializer_class = FuzzySerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    ordering_fields = ['id']
    filter_class = FuzzyFilter
```

FuzzyFilter looks like this:

```
class FuzzyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    simplified = filters.CharFilter(field_name='simplified', lookup_expr='contains')
    traditional = filters.CharFilter(field_name='traditional', lookup_expr='contains')
    pinyin_marks = filters.CharFilter(field_name='pinyin_marks', lookup_expr='contains')
    translation = filters.CharFilter(field_name='translation', lookup_expr='icontains')
    frequency = filters.CharFilter(field_name='frequency', lookup_expr='exact')
    hsk = NumberInFilter(field_name='level', lookup_expr='in')
```

And I do a call like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/fuzzy/?translation=One
```

I'll only get results that contain "One", never results that contain "one", and vice versa.

I am using MySQL as my database engine, but as far as I can tell, my collations are correct for case insensitive searching:

[image: MySQL Database table]

I am on Django 3.x.

What could possibly be causing it/what's the best method to resolve/troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does requesting `?translation__icontains=One` give you the same results?

Comment: No, that seems to find me every result - like without any filter whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

I had the particular field, translation, set to binary.

When I unchecked this, it worked as intended.